# using Composites with Shell for java in eclipse with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, swt

I have a java maven project in eclipse that is using some Composites, however I am having trouble when creating a main method to launch my widgets.

I added the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rap</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.rap.rwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my main method (where MainWindow is my composite)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(450,256);
    shell.setText("My Title");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow(shell, SWT.ALL);
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()){
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

If I try to run this application from within eclipse I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context available outside of the request processing.
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.ContextProvider.getContext(ContextProvider.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.ContextProvider.getUISession(ContextProvider.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.LifeCycleUtil.setSessionDisplay(LifeCycleUtil.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:275)
```

While if I execute this after compiling it as a jar I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Layout
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

How can I get my application to launch?
Thanks

Update:

The NoClassdefFound was solved by using a jar-with-dependency in the build plugin.

The No Context available error however now pops up on both executions (cmd and eclipse)

Comment: Do you actually want to use Eclipse RAP or just SWT?

Comment: ah! that was it. I had added that to get some dependnecies. thanks. post the answer. I just removed the rap dependency and it booted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including the Eclipse RAP versions of SWT which are not used for normal SWT applications.

Remove the RAP dependencies and just use normal SWT.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should specify SWT dependency for your OS. For example here is dependency for OS X:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/swt-repo/) list of dependencies for other OS-es.

Comment: I'm still getting the same NoClassDef

Comment: Check that Eclipse load this dependency or try to build and run app from terminal.

Comment: the NoClassDef error happens when building and running from temrinal.  The IllegalStateExcpetion (no context available) comes when running from within eclipse

Comment: update:
the noClassdefFound was solved by using a jar-with-dependency in the build plugin. The No Context available error however now pops up on both executions (cmd and eclipse)